# Como eu posso usar o comando UPDATE entre duas tabelas?

Tags: sql, firebird

Estou tentando atualizar o campo `GRUPO` da tabela `ESTOQUE` para o valor 1 (um) quando o campo `NCM` da tabela `EST_ADICIONAIS` for igual a `21011000`. Sendo que, ambas as tabelas tem o campo `CODIGO` com valores iguais. Utilizo firebird.

Comment: Você tem algum sql que tentou fazer?

Comment: Outra coisa, se possível poste a estrutura das tabelas, pois precisamos disso para que seja feito o sql corretamente

Comment: Poderia tentar esse SQL e dizer o resultado (não testei)? `UPDATE estoque as est INNER JOIN est_adicionais as eadd ON eadd.codigo = est.codigo SET est.grupo = 1  WHERE eadd.ncm = 21011000`

Comment: Refael: Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 1, column 16.
as.

Comment: Acabei de atualizar ele... podia tentar novamente?

Comment: Tenta esse sql para ver se dá certo: update estoque set estoque.grupo = 1 where estoque inner join est_adicionais on (estoque.codigo = est_adicionais.codigo)
where est_adicionais.ncm = 21011000

Comment: Eu testei depois que você atualizou, e me retornou o erro do meu comentario anterior

Comment: Giovane, me retornou o erro : Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 1, column 52.
inner.

Comment: @Washington, testa desse jeito: update ESTOQUE 
inner join EST_ADICIONAIS on EST_ADICIONAIS.CODIGO = ESTOQUE.CODIGO where EST_ADICIONAIS.NCM = '21011000'
SET ESTOQUE.GRUPO = 1. É do mesmo jeito proposto pelo Rafael só mudei a posição do WHERE.

Comment: @Washington, acredito que seja melhor você postar a imagem da relação entre as tabelas. Pode ser que a gente acabe te induzindo ao erro dessa forma.

Answer (score 1):

Com base na vaga ideia que tenho das suas tabelas criei um [exemplo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fbe20/1) para simular a sua instrução SQL.

Criei as tabelas com a seguinte estrutura:

- ESTOQUE (CODIGO INT, GRUPO INT)
- EST_ADICIONAIS (CODIGO INT, NCM varchar(8))

Fiz os inserts necessários e, para atualizar, conforme a necessidade exigida, executei o seguinte SQL:

```
UPDATE ESTOQUE INNER JOIN EST_ADICIONAIS ON ESTOQUE.CODIGO = EST_ADICIONAIS.CODIGO AND EST_ADICIONAIS.NCM = '21011000' SET ESTOQUE.GRUPO = 1
```

Comment: Geison Santos, executei e me retornou o erro : Invalid token.
Dynamic SQL Error.
SQL error code = -104.
Token unknown - line 2, column 1.
INNER.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que entendi, Washington, acredito que esse comando vai te ajudar:

```
update estoque est 
set est.grupo = 1
where est.codigo in (
    select est_adi.codigo from est_adicionais est_adi where est_adi.ncm = '21011000'
)
```